# Equipotential surfaces for a knotted charge distribution

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, mathematics, topology

Suppose we have a compact submanifold $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with uniformly distributed charge.  Neglecting multiplicative constants, the electric potential $\Phi(\vec{x}) = \int_{K} \frac{dK}{|x - k|}$. (The type of integral depends on the dimension of $K$).

For a small voltage level $R$, it is understood that the equipotential surface $\Phi^{-1}(R)$ is topologically equivalent to a sphere encapsulating $K$. Likewise, for a large voltage level $R$, $\Phi^{-1}(R)$ is the boundary of a tubular neighborhood of $K$.

How can we rigorously justify this mathematically? For the low voltage surface, I was thinking one could use a far point charge approximation, which has spheres as its equipotential surfaces, but how do we know the topology of the level surfaces are preserved?

My background is in mathematics, but this is a problem of a physical nature. Ultimately, I'm interested in the case where $K$ is a smooth knot with zero thickness, but I think the answer to my question is the result of some general principle regarding charge distributions.

Comment: The physical intuition behind the statement is pretty clear; what do you mean by a "rigorous" justification? Do you want something all the way down to the level of tracking $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s?

Comment: Yes. That’s what I’m looking for.